# My Chinese Redmi 4A showed me a step counter in the screen to the left of the home screen but my non-Chinese Redmi 6 does not

Tags: xiaomi, miui, redmi, miui-10, redmi-6

I bought my old Redmi 4A in China less than two years ago. I never installed most of the Google infrastructure on it. I did upgrade to MIUI 10.

I just bought a Redmi 6 in Taiwan so it does have all the Google infrastructure and lacks some of the Xiaomi and/or Chinese internet apps etc.

Recently I noticed if I swipe right on the home screen on the 4A I see among other info the number of steps I've walked today. I did not have a step counter app installed . The 4A had very little storage so you always delete apps you don't use.

On my new Redmi 6 I don't see the number of steps I've walked.

How can I enable this feature on my 6, or at least find out what app etc the 4A got this info from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself after some Googling. This is a feature of the China ROM that is not present in the non-China ROM.

MIUI Forum: [[Feature Request] Step counter absent!](http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=1447568&page=1)

This feature was reported missing since at least January 2018. So far I haven't found anything on whether it's going to be added to the non-China ROM.